Is it OK for Electron app to store source code in sqlite database and than later execute using `new Function`
The application I'm working at the moment requires to store some source code on the client's machine, so it could be executed later.
So I chose to store it in the sqlite database and than execute it using:
new Function(sourceCodeTakenFromDatabase)()

But the security side of such approach bothers me. Can someone confirm - is it OK to do so in terms of security and if it's not - why not and what measures should I take to make it safe?
PS: The Context
I need it to store "down migrations".
In our application we want to have an ability to easily and quickly revert to the previous version of the application if we found some serious problem in the current one. But there is a problem - migrations - if the new version of the app had migrations we can't just download and reinstall the previous version of the app - we also have to apply "down migrations" to keep the database state consistent. But the previous version of the app doesn't have these "down migrations" because they came with the new version.
So the idea is to store these "down migrations" in the database after the "up migrations" were applied. Later when we have to revert to the previous version of the app we can take them from the database and execute.

The business logic is flawed, because with each new version you could provide both. Migration should better be one-way, because data may otherwise being dropped, unrecoverable unless having stored it elsewhere.

To add to Martin's comment, one-way migrations aren't a big deal because you should be testing your product before shipping it out to production. This would catch such "serious problems" and gives you time to fix any you've found before your users/customers notice.

In addition to what has been said in the comments, to answer the original question: Well, it depends on your definition of "OK."
Executing code from any source other than what your app is being shipped with is an inherently bad idea, especially if it's so general as outlined in your question. You'll need to consider these functions untrusted input because you cannot guarantee that the database file hasn't been compromised and therefore cannot guarantee that the code stored there is not malicious.
Of course, you could (e.g.) only store and execute code that's been signed by you (e.g. with your private OpenPGP key). But even then you'd have to think about managing keys and this will create other problems (at the latest when you realise that the previous version expects a different signing key so all your nice migration procedures won't even run).
The simplest solution is often the best: Test your product for all eventualities (by using unit testing and, if necessary, manual testing) and you'll most likely won't need to have such a system in place.
Otherwise, this is just another attack vector against your application with little value.
Please note that this does not specifically apply to "storing code for later use." This advice applies to any scenario in which you would load code off the user's machine you potentially don't know.
